# How to use Ajax call correctly to send form data to Webserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I am trying to implement a form containing a list of cities, using a JSON array and an autocomplete function.

My ajax call is successful and gives the expected success alert, but I'm still not getting the JSON array data.

The problem is that my suggest_json_application function is failing at the 'if form.has_key('term')' statement and giving the message "form has no key".

How can I pass the form data to the function properly through the ajax call, with the key `term`?

HTML form

```
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset><legend>Cities</legend>
  <input type='text' name='term' id='term'>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var term = $('#term').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/suggestjson",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({'term': term}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            console.log( data );
        }    
    }); 
});
```

Webserver

```
cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Los Angeles', 
          'Paris', 'San Francisco', 'Adelaide']

if environ['PATH_INFO'] == "/suggestjson":
    return suggest_json_application(environ, start_response)


def suggest_json_application(environ, start_response):
    //Return JSON array of completions for a city name

    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=environ)

    if form.has_key('term'):
        print "form has key"
        q = form.getvalue("term", "")
        matches = [c for c in cities if c.lower().startswith(q.lower())]
    else:
        print "form has no key"
        matches = []

    return json.dumps(matches)
```

Comment: You should use POST instead of get to send data to server

Comment: var term = $('input[name=term]').val(); it should be first

Comment: Try to use `POST` and stringify your data: `data: JSON.stringify({'term': term})`.

Comment: @amanda23 I think that you have missed something in your Python code, I didn't know much about it, just some notes: (1) `cgi` doesn't need to import? (2) `has_key` is removed from version 3. (3) try to find the typeof `form["term"]`. _maybe you already did it, ofcourse_ `:)`

Comment: @amanda23 what is $('#term') i dont see that in your html instead should it be $('#city') ??

Comment: @amanda23 good to hear. try to print `form["term"]`, it must contains a JSON string. If it is, you must parse it as json, maybe something like this: `data = json.loads(form["term"])` (don't forget to `import json`.

Comment: When you are revising your OP, please indicate that on the skeleton question you leave behind so that others do not attempt to answer a question that is unrelated to what you eventually re-post.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are sending whole html element to server. Invoke `val()` function to get the value of element,

Also use id selector for easy access to element,

like this:

```
var term = $('#term').val();
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that but it doesn't make a difference since my console still shows me "form has no key" message

Answer (score 0):

Use val() :- see details [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
    var term = $('#term').val();
```

and also data parameter in ajax it should be

```
    data : {term: term}
```

Comment: thanks, i've updated both but still the console tells me "form has no key" in my webserver

Answer (score 0):

please try to change "data" option to a object in the ajax call as follow

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var term = $('input[name=city]');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/suggestjson",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {'term': term},
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
        console.log( data );

    }     
  }); 
});
```